# Why the expected file is not created in VS code with fstream?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, text-files, fstream

I am a beginner at file handling and I tried to create a file to store some data into a file in text format. But the expected text file is not created in the location I tried to create and when I search for the expected file using the name, it shows that there is no such file. So the file has not been created.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream firstFile;
    firstFile.open("testFile.txt", ios::out);
    
    if (firstFile.is_open())
    {
        firstFile << "My name is ABCD & this is my first text file in cpp";
        firstFile.close();
    }

    cout << "This code is working properly";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting `testFile.txt` to be located?

Comment: @DrewDormann In the same location where the source file is there

Comment: Look elsewhere.  Your program does not know where its source code was stored.  Since your program does not specify an exact location for the file, it will be in the [_current working directory_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: It usually stores the file in the same directory in which the executable is located. Search the whole system directories and not just the working directory of VS Code.

Comment: Better still, specify an absolute path (or jump through a few hoops and track down the current user's home directory).

Comment: How this question is related to the editor `vscode`.